# How to change a column values with non-continuous numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe. I wanto to change the values in the column "label".
The values must go from 1 to 7, but # 4 must not be used. Also there must be 2 of each one.

I have managed to do it. But my method is only useful for small dataframes.
So how can I make it automatic for bigger dataframes?

```
#Original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 5))
label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
df['label'] = label
df

#My attempt :)
df['label'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]
df
```

ORIGINAL DATAFRAME

[image]

EXPECTED DATAFRAME (# 4 is missing!!!)

[image]

Comment: For longer datasets, would you like to skip 8, 12, 16 and so on too?

Comment: Nope. Just the 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use floor division and add >= 4

```
label = np.arange(len(df)) // 2 + 1
df['label'] = label + (label >= 4)

df
```

[image]